# Android studio - Aplicacion se cierra cuando intento acceder a una bd en servidor

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Estoy trabajando con **android studio**, cree una aplicación la cual me permite leer datos de una base de datos en un servidor y cargar los datos en la base de datos **sqlite** que tiene **android**.

Cuando lo hago en mi emulador genymotion todo va bien, tengo un tablet samsung con android 5.1.1, instalo la aplicacion y logro una conexion perfecta (puedo leer los datos de la web y cargarlos en sqlite).

El problema está cuando intento instalar en otra tablet con android 5.1.1, en estos casos cuando intento leer de la web la aplicación se cierra. ¿Alguna idea de porqué no me funciona en las otras tablet? Necesito tener instalado algún paquete o apk en la tablet que no funciona?

Parte del código

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method.equals("POST")){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method.equals("GET")){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                //httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", "__test=06410fea214b2febfb23d387de6037da; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/");
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {

            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}


 protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            BaseHelper baseHelper = new BaseHelper(MyActivity.this, "DEMODB", null, 1);
            //Elimino todos los datos de la tabla producto (base sqlite tablet)
            baseHelper.vaciarTabla("producto",baseHelper);

            // Building Parameters
            List params = new ArrayList();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(urlProductos, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    //Log.i("ramiro", "produtos.length" + products.length());
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String codigo = c.getString(TAG_CODIGO);
                        String nombre = c.getString(TAG_NOMBRE);
                        String lista = c.getString(TAG_LISTA);
                        String preciou = c.getString(TAG_PRECIOU);
                        String preciobr = c.getString(TAG_PRECIOBR);
                        String stock = c.getString(TAG_STOCK);
                        String fecha = c.getString(TAG_FECHA);

                        System.out.println(id+" "+codigo+" "+lista+" "+nombre);

                        // inserto en mi tabla local
                        SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                        if (db != null) {
                            ContentValues registroNuevo = new ContentValues();
                            //primer parametro nombre en la base, segundo el valor a ingresar
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_id", id);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_codigo", codigo);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_nombre", nombre);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_lista", lista);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_precio_u", preciou);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_precio_br", preciobr);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_stock", stock);
                            registroNuevo.put("prd_fecha_update", fecha);
                            long z = db.insert("producto", null, registroNuevo);
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: La tablet en la que anda bien es ken brown...en la samsung no anda!

Comment: Conecta la tablet a Android estudio para ver qué error da

Comment: Solucionado! El problema era el servidor, estaba usando un servidor gratis que hace ciertas verificaciones con las cookies, y si yo seteaba ese valor  

httpGet.addHeader("Cookie", "__test=06410fea214b2febfb23d387de6037da; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/");

funcionaba bien en mi tablet y en mi emulador, pero cuando queria probar con otra tablet en otro lugar fallaba. Cuando cambie de servidor todo funciono perfectamente, sin necesidad de setear "httpGet.addHeader("Cookie"..."